# Exporting from MySQL to an Object array in PHP and then JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I have the code below that is passing data from MySQL to a PHP array:

```
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $profile[] = array(
        "id" => $row[ "id" ],
        "first" => $row[ "first" ],
        "last" => $row[ "last" ],
        "cell" => $row[ "cell" ],
        "email" => $row[ "email" ],
        "kids" => $row[ "kids" ]
    );
}
```

I'm then encoding this into JavaScript like so:

```
var userprofile = <?php echo json_encode($profile); ?>;
```

The output of which is

[image]

To get a parameter I have to do `userprofile[0].cell` where as I want to just do `userprofile.cell`

What do I have to change to get the desired outcome?

There is only ever one result

Comment: Well if there is only one element: `$profile = array(...`? instead of pushing that value on... `$profile[] = array(`

Comment: unless you are dropping some fields that we can't see you can just do `$profile = $row` since the keys are all the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this line:

```
var userprofile = <?php echo json_encode($profile); ?>;
```

It looks like you've run a query to fetch one row containing profile data for a single user.

But the way you're fetching it with

```
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $profile[] = array(...
```

is how you would set it up if you wanted to return multiple user profiles.

I think what you need instead is simply:

```
$profile = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

If there are other columns in the profile that you don't want to send, you can just specify the columns you want in your query. (`SELECT id, first, last, etc.` instead of `SELECT *`.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
var single = {"foo": 1, "bar": 2};
//PHP would be array('foo' => 1, 'bar' => 2);

var list = [{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}];
//PHP would be array(array('foo' => 1, 'bar' => 2)); ... what you do with []... array_push.

console.log(list[0].foo);

console.log(single.foo);
```

Are you creating an "object", or an array of objects? If the later then you would need to reference the object at the proper offset. Obvious when stated, hopefully the code will make it evident.